# Lync sdk work with Asterisk?

Tags: c#, voip, asterisk, lync-2010, lync

I have a requirement to develop a VoIP client with wpf/silverlight. I heard that Microsoft Lync is a good option but I would like to use the developed application against Asterisk server (VoIP server) instead of Lync 2010 server.

I already have an application developed with Microsoft UCCAPI which works fine with Asterisk server. so I want to know whether Lync sdk supports the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think only Lync server supports SIP.

Answer (score 0):

You could use all Lync SDK Development phases including Lync SDK, UCMA, UCMA workflow and UI Suppression mode.

Also Lync supports only the SIP protocol but you can integrate your client to work with diffrent protocols like h.323 by creating an UCMA user endpoint to recieve the SIP request and try to negotiate with the h.323 endpoint and start the process of encoding and decoding the stream.

I hope this may help.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you want to deploy something using Lync with Asterisk,  take a look of [SimpLync.](http://www.simplync.net)   SimpLync is a plugin that inserts on Lync client, acting as a sofphone, and connecting to Asterisk, obtaining full integration.  The advantage of this approach is that with simplync you have also a powerful scripting language, so you can introduce your own integrations with additional system, login on asterisk queues, etc.  This [post](http://news.simplync.net/2015/09/22/simplync-register-lync-clients-on-your-sip-pbx/) explain further the possibilities.